# Connect the mongodb running on remote machine

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

MongoDB is running on remote machine which is accessible through my machine. I try to give the command in my machine

telnet "remote machine ip" 27017

It can able to connect.

But if I connect in the client by giving this command

mongo "machine ip" --port 27017 -u sample -p sample --authenticationDatabase admin

I am getting  "Authentication failed" error.

But using that user name and password I can able to connect in remote machine. also in mongod.cfg file enabled the property "bindIpAll" as true.

is there any point I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

When you get an "Authentication failed" error, then you are already connected MongoDB.

You must put **db address** to the end or specify as option, i.e.

```
mongo --port 27017 -u sample -p sample --authenticationDatabase admin "machine ip"
```

or

```
mongo --host "machine ip" --port 27017 -u sample -p sample --authenticationDatabase admin
```

> ```
> c:\>mongo -h
> MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
> usage: mongo [options] [db address] [file names (ending in .js)]
> db address can be:
>   foo                   foo database on local machine
>   192.168.0.5/foo       foo database on 192.168.0.5 machine
>   192.168.0.5:9999/foo  foo database on 192.168.0.5 machine on port 9999
>   mongodb://192.168.0.5:9999/foo  connection string URI can also be used
> ```